# bootstrap combining rowspan and colspan

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am testing Bootstrap 3 and got stuck with basic scaffolding with rows. I revisited their documentation number of times and I can see nesting columns where you can basically nest columns within a column but I cannot locate the capability of combining rows into one and have it aligned with column next to the uncombined rows.

Below picture should illustrate what I want to accomplish.
[image: layout schema]
[image: desired design]

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-HSMxcRTRxnN+Bdg0JdbxYKrThecOKuH5zCYotlSAcp1+c8xmyTe9GYg1l9a69psu" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="thm-container">


  <div class="row" style="background-color:red;">

    <div class="col-md-3">
      <div class="single-feature-style-five">
        <div class="inner-box">
          <div class="content">
            <h3>PPE</h3>

            <a href="#" class="more">Find out how <i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i></a>
          </div>
          <!-- /.content -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.inner-box -->
      </div>
      <!-- /.single-feature-style-five -->
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-9">

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="single-feature-style-five" style="background-color:orange;">
            <div class="inner-box">
              <div class="content">
                <h3>PPE</h3>

                <a href="#" class="more">Find out how <i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i></a>
              </div>
              <!-- /.content -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.inner-box -->
          </div>
          <!-- /.single-feature-style-five -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.col-md-4 -->
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="single-feature-style-five" style="background-color:violet;">
            <div class="inner-box">
              <div class="content">
                <h3>A Step Sterlization</h3>

                <a href="#" class="more">Find out how <i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i></a>
              </div>
              <!-- /.content -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.inner-box -->
          </div>
          <!-- /.single-feature-style-five -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.col-md-4 -->
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="single-feature-style-five" style="background-color:brown;">
            <div class="inner-box">
              <div class="content">
                <h3>Fumigator</h3>

                <a href="#" class="more">Find out how <i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i></a>
              </div>
              <!-- /.content -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.inner-box -->
          </div>
          <!-- /.single-feature-style-five -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.col-md-4 -->
      </div>
      <!-- /.row -->

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="single-feature-style-five" style="background-color:yellow;">
            <div class="inner-box">
              <div class="content">
                <h3>PPE</h3>

                <a href="#" class="more">Find out how <i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i></a>
              </div>
              <!-- /.content -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.inner-box -->
          </div>
          <!-- /.single-feature-style-five -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.col-md-4 -->
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="single-feature-style-five" style="background-color:blue;">
            <div class="inner-box">
              <div class="content">
                <h3>A Step Sterlization</h3>

                <a href="#" class="more">Find out how <i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i></a>
              </div>
              <!-- /.content -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.inner-box -->
          </div>
          <!-- /.single-feature-style-five -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.col-md-4 -->
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="single-feature-style-five" style="background-color:black;">
            <div class="inner-box">
              <div class="content">
                <h3>Fumigator</h3>

                <a href="#" class="more">Find out how <i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i></a>
              </div>
              <!-- /.content -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.inner-box -->
          </div>
          <!-- /.single-feature-style-five -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.col-md-4 -->
      </div>
      <!-- /.row -->

    </div>
  </div>



</div>
<!-- /.thm-container -->
```

Comment: You can't get this layout with out of the box functionality of bootstrap (neither 3 or 4). You will have to adapt the CSS to get the desired output. Columns have spacing between them, I would advise to just create your own HTML and CSS for this component.

Answer (score -2):

Hope this helps you:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="Stylesheet" href="row-col.css">   
<html>         
</head>
<Body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4 left"></div>
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <div class="row right-top"></div>
                <div class="row right-bottom"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</Body>
</html>
```

and css:

```
.left {
    background:#ff2842;
    height:100vh;
}
.right-top {
    height:50vh;
    background:#ffc600;
}
.right-bottom {
    height: 50vh;
    background:#2f303a;
}
```